# Recoger datos de un input

Tags: javascript, html

Estoy intentando recoger los datos de un input y no hay manera. A ver si podéis echarme una mano porque me he atascado...

```
<body>
<div id="monedero" class="flex-container">
    <form>
        <input type="text" name="campoTexto" maxlength="3" size="3" 
         title="Introduce el número de monedas" id="campoTexto">
    </form>
    <button type="button" id="boton">Insertar</button>
</div>

<script src="tragaperras.js"></script>
</body>



var campoTextoValue = document.getElementsById("campoTexto");


function miFuncion(){
   console.log(campoTextoValue);
}

document.getElementById("boton").addEventListener("click", miFuncion);
```

El mensaje por consola me recoge la ejecución de la función, pero me sale vacío, no recoge los datos que introduzco en el campo en el campo de texto.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Necesitas la funcion para coger el valor del input, además, te sobra una "s", se quedaria:

```
document.getElementById("campoTexto").value
```

De la forma que lo tienes ahora mismo estas recogiendo el elemento en sí, es decir, la etiqueta input completa.

Comment: Muchas gracias, llevaba ya unas hora bloqueado y no veía la "s".

Mil gracias.